# SQL Foreign Key General Error 1215 when creating migrations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I built two migrations:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('incidents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->integer('incident_type_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('incident_reference');
        $table->integer('incident_id');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->time('time');
        $table->string('location');
        $table->string('street');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->double('latitude', 10, 6);
        $table->double('longitude', 10, 6);
        $table->smallInteger('incident_archived')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and the other one:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('responders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->string('responder_id');
        $table->integer('incident_id');
        $table->foreign('incident_id')->references('incident_id')->on('incidents');
        $table->double('last_lat', 10, 6);
        $table->double('last_lng', 10, 6);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Now I want to use the incident_id as foreign key to the incidents table. But I get the error: Cannot add foreign key constraint. First I thought it is order of migrations that causes trouble, so the responder table would be created before the incident table. But this is not the case. So why am I blocked using incident_id as foreign key then?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I posted an answer but removed it since I didn't read properly. May I ask why you have an id on incidents as well as an incident_id? Either way, I would suggest adding `->unsigned()` to the `incident_id` columns in both migrations.

Comment: Hi Joel, I added the `->unsigned()` but it is still the same error.

Comment: Just struck me - is your `incident_id` column on the incidents table actually an index? It's not enough to just make it an integer, it has to be an index as well.

Comment: Oh. nope.. it is not an index. Hm... let me try it!

Comment: But why can't I use a custom column that is not an index?

Comment: Basically for performance: "InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan." (from the documentation)